Flutter: Multiple data insert in firebase real-time database but app is stuck
Future<void> addExpenseInDatabase(BuildContext context) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> splitByMap = {};
    Map<String, dynamic> paidByMap = {};
    for (var element in splitByList) {
      String dateTime = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
      splitByMap[dateTime] = element.toJson();
    }
    for (var element in paidByList) {
      String dateTime = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
      paidByMap[dateTime] = element.toJson();
    }
    getIt<CustomDialogs>().showCircularDialog(context);
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5)).then((value) async {
      DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
      formattedDate.value = formatter.format(selectedDate.value);
      if (!isNullEmptyOrFalse(amountController.value.text)) {
        if (paidByList.isNotEmpty && splitByList.isNotEmpty) {
          await FirebaseHelper.addAndEditExpense(
            isEdit: isFromExpenseEdit.isTrue,
            groupID: groupModel.value.groupID.toString(),
            expenseId: expenseList.value.expenseID.toString(),
            description: descriptionController.value.text,
            iconPath: selectedCategory.value.icon.toString(),
            currency: selectedCurrency.value,
            amount: amountController.value.text,
            expenseDate: formattedDate.value,
            notes: noteController.value.text,
            paidByList: paidByMap,
            splitByList: splitByMap,
          ).then((value) {
            activityList.add(ActivityModel(
              image: groupModel.value.groupImage.toString(),
              groupType: groupModel.value.groupType.toString(),
              title: isFromExpenseEdit.isTrue == true
                  ? "You updated '${descriptionController.value.text}' in '${groupModel.value.groupName}'"
                  : "You added '${descriptionController.value.text}' in '${groupModel.value.groupName}'",
              date: DateTime.now().toString(),
            ));
            List<Map<String, dynamic>> activityListJson = activityList.map((friend) => friend.toJson()).toList();
            box.write(ArgumentConstant.activityList, activityListJson);
            List<Map<String, dynamic>> splitByListJson = [];
            box.write(ArgumentConstant.passSplitByList, splitByListJson);
            List<Map<String, dynamic>> paidByListJson = [];
            box.write(ArgumentConstant.passPaidByList, paidByListJson);
            getIt<CustomDialogs>().hideCircularDialog(context);
            Get.back();
          },);
        } else {
          getIt<CustomDialogs>().hideCircularDialog(context);
          Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Enter paid by and split by");
        }
      } else {
        getIt<CustomDialogs>().hideCircularDialog(context);
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Enter description and amount");
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode);
      }
    });
  }

I need to insert multiple data at a time in the Firebase real-time database. This function is responsible for adding an expense record to a database and updating local UI components based on whether the operation was successful or not. It includes data validation, asynchronous database operations, and UI feedback.
